# Adding image alt attribute field

Tags: php, wordpress, image, function, alt

I've got these codes:

```
$slider_gallery.= '<span class="chpcs_img"><a href="'.$post_link.'">'.$this->get_post_image($post->ID,$image_size).'</a></span>';
```

```
public  function get_post_image($post_image_id, $img_size) {

    if (has_post_thumbnail($post_image_id)):
        $img_arr = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post_image_id), $img_size); $first_img = $img_arr[0];
    endif;

    if (empty($first_img)) {
        if (empty($this->options['settings']['default_image_url'])) {
            $first_img = plugins_url('assets/images/default-image.jpg', __FILE__);
        }
        else {
            $first_img = $this->options['settings']['default_image_url'];
        }
    }
    $first_img = "<img src='".$first_img. "' />";
    return $first_img;
}
```

I'm trying to add alt attribute but can't figure out. By the way that's wordpress plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/carousel-horizontal-posts-content-slider/  on /plugins/carousel-horizontal-posts-content-slider/chpcs.php

line 340 and line 404-427

Comment: So you want to pass image file name as alt attribute?

Comment: Yes trying like that $first_img = "<img src='". $first_img. "' alt='"try to getting image file name or getting image alt info from wp gallery"' />";
    return $first_img;
}

Comment: I presume that $post_image_id is the name of image?

Comment: Thanks @RyanCyrus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass $img_alt in your function.

```
public  function get_post_image($post_image_id, $img_size, $img_alt) {

    if (has_post_thumbnail( $post_image_id ) ): 
     $img_arr = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_image_id ), $img_size ); $first_img = $img_arr[0];

    endif; 

    if(empty($first_img)) {

    if(empty($this->options['settings']['default_image_url'])) {

         $first_img = plugins_url('assets/images/default-image.jpg', __FILE__);

    } else {

        $first_img = $this->options['settings']['default_image_url'];

    }
}
  $first_img = "<img src='". $first_img. "' alt='". $img_alt. "' />";
  return $first_img;
}
```

and then your calling line will be

```
$slider_gallery.= '<span class="chpcs_img"><a href="'.$post_link.'">'.$this->get_post_image($post->ID,$image_size, "Alt text").'</a></span>';
```

Comment: Thanks mate, too close but result is; same alt text, every image, i want to use different text every image like image title or (i'm upload images to wp gallery and every image have alt attri.) gallery alt attr. if possible.. There's the results screenshot [link](http://i.hizliresim.com/37NlBj.jpg)

Comment: @DmN well obviously mate. I just showed you a way to do it. You did not show us your loop / how you are getting the slider images. If you are getting your slider images from db then you add an `image_alt` column there and then change `"Alt text"` in the `$this->get_post_image($post->ID,$image_size, "Alt text")` to something like `$post->image_alt` then your alt will be different for images. If you need help with that let me know

Comment: thanks mate you right, i'm newb on php and can't explain my problem clearly because of my english. I will do that now thank you. Use `.$this->get_post_image($post->ID,$image_size,$post->post_tit‌​le).'</a></span>';` and change `$img_alt` to `$post_title` than ok. there's the result [php example](http://whatisthewik.com/php/) on bottom of page slider, thanks again.

Comment: Really glad you could figure it out